# Python: ImportError: cannot import name 'BeautifulSoup'

Tags: python, python-3.x, console, pycharm

I have always used R and now trying to switch to Python. 
I'm using Pycharm and found this error when running the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
example1 = BeautifulSoup(train["review"][0],"lxml")
print (example1.get_text())
```

When I run it I have:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'BeautifulSoup'
```

But I don't have any problem using the console. The rest of the code works fine both with the Run command/terminal and console.

Thank you for your help

Comment: Which version of python do you have on the pycharm interpreter? are you using the same interpreter as in your console?

Comment: Python 3.5.2 and I'm using the same version :/

Answer (score 0):

Oh,I think you should check your file name or folder name.If there is a name that is already used in bs4 module,you will got ImportError.

Hope this helps.